# Disable Sorting for specific columns of Clarity Data Grid

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is it possible to disable the only the sorting feature for specific column of a data grid.

Calrity version is 2.1.2

Comment: The built in `clrDgItem` attribute on columns adds both sorting and filtering by design. There may be some use cases that only sorting or only filtering is needed. These use cases have been difficult to define. The thinking behind this decision is that for most use cases, if you need to filter, you also need to sort (and vicey-versey). There are some things the app could do to hide the filter icon or disable the column text hover with css. If you post an https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team with an example of your datagrid I can take a look at it.